# Vagrant overwrites host files during provision

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, rsync

I have been having an issue when vagrant overwrites the host files during when I run `vagrnat provision`.

In the `src` folder on my host machine (my laptop), I have a git repo with a `.git` folder and all the actual files that I use in the repo. When I run `vagrant provision` vagrant purges `/var/www/site` and because the folders are synced, destroy my host machine's copy of my `site` folder. Am I doing something wrong with folder syncing?

I'm running on `Windows 7` with `Vagrant 1.6.3` and`Virtualbox 4.3.12`

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|  

  #Run a shell provisioner that installs the puppet-mongodb module
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "manifests/install_modules.sh"

  # Enable the Puppet provisioner, with will look in manifests
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "default.pp"
    puppet.module_path = "modules"
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
  end

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "precise32"

  # Forward guest port 80 to host port 8888 and name mapping
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8001
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 443, host: 8002

  config.vm.synced_folder "site/", "/var/www/site", :owner => "www-data"

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Whoops! I realized I had a line in my puppet config file that forced the `var/www` to be purged. This was actually a mistake in my puppet configs.

**I changed this:**

```
#Create the directory
file {["/var/www","/var/www/virt-env"]:
    ensure => directory,
    recurse => true,
    purge => true,
    force => true,
    before => [
        File["/var/www/virt-env/requirements.txt"],
        Class['python']
    ],
}
```

**To this:**

```
#Create the directory
file{"/var/www":
    ensure => directory
    before => File["/var/www/virt-env/"]
}

file {"/var/www/virt-env":
    ensure => directory,
    recurse => true,
    purge => true,
    force => true,
    before => [
        File["/var/www/virt-env/requirements.txt"],
        Class['python']
    ],
}
```